# R Plotly: Smaller markers in bubble plot

Tags: r, plotly, markers, bubble-chart

I'm making a bubble plot in Plotly (for R) and I keep getting overlapping markers. Is there a way to "scale down" all markers, so that their relative sizes are preserved but there is no overlap? I want to keep the dimensions of plot the same. Here's a test case:

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=14))
colnames(test) <- c("Group", "Numbers", "Days")
loop<- 1
for(i in 1:7){
    test[i,] <- c(1, i, loop)
    loop <- loop * 1.5
}
loop <- 1
for(i in 1:7){
    test[i+7,] <- c(2, i, loop)
    loop <- loop * 1.3
}
plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, size=Days, mode="markers")
```

[image: booo overlapping markers]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this sort of thing is to adjust the `sizeref` (and `size`) argument in `marker`:

```
plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, mode="markers",
    marker = list(size = Days, sizeref = 0.15))

plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, mode="markers", 
    marker = list(size = Days/2, sizeref = 0.1))

plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, size = Days, mode="markers",
    marker = list(sizeref = 2.5)) # Days data in the hoverinfo with this method
```

From https://plot.ly/r/reference/:

> sizeref (number)
>   default: 1
>   Has an effect only if `marker.size` is
>   set to a numerical array. Sets the scale factor used to determine the
>   rendered size of marker points. Use with `sizemin` and `sizemode`.

If you wanted the hover text to match your original plot, you could define it explicitly:

```
plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, mode="markers",
    marker = list(size = Days, sizeref = 0.15),
    hoverinfo = "text", 
    text = paste0("(", Group, ", ", Numbers, ")<br>", "Days (size): ", Days))
```

Comment: I had seen the `sizeref`, but didn't know it had to used this way. Thanks so much!